# How to check if module attribute is a Class

Tags: python

I am using `imp.find_module` and then `imp.load_module` to load `'example'`, now I want to make a list of just the functions in `example.py` that are functions of `Class A` but I can't seem to find a `getattr` attribute that is unique to Classes which would filter out all other methods in `dir(example)`.

```
for i in dir(example):
    if hasattr(getattr(example, i), <some_attribute>):
        print i
```

Comment: Btw, "module method" is wrong term. Method is always function, and what you are accessing are module attributes. All methods are attributes (initially), not all attributes are methods.

Comment: Also, using `dir()` anywhere except interactive prompt is considered bad practice, because it's slow and inconsistent. If you need to access list of attributes for some reason, iterate over `__dict__` or `__slots__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you search for existing solution, use builtin [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isclass) module, it has plenty of functions to test for specific types, [`isclass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isclass) for your case:

```
import inspect

class Foo(object):
    pass

if inspect.isclass(Foo):
   print("Yep, it's class")
```

However, if you want to get into depths, there are few other approaches.

1. In Python everything is an instance of something. Classes are not an exclusion, they are instances of *metaclasses*. In Python 2 there are two kinds of classes — old-style (`class Foo: pass`) and new-style (`class Foo(object): pass`). Old-style classes are instances of `classobj`, visible as `types.ClassType`, while new-style classes are instances of `type`, which itself is both function and metaclass at the same time (callable metaclass to be strict). In Python 3, there are only new-style classes, always derived from `object` (which in turn is instance of `type`).

   So, you can check if `Foo` is class, by issuing if it's an instance of metaclass producing classes:

   ```
   class Foo(object):
       pass

   if isinstance(Foo, type):
       print("Yep, it's new-style class")
   ```

   Or for old-style:

   ```
   import types

   class Foo:
       pass

   if isinstance(Foo, types.ClassType):
       print("Yep, it's old-style class")
   ```
2. You can also take a look at [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) and [list of class-specific magic fields](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__).

Comment: Found that isinstance(getattr(V, i), (type, types.ClassType)) seems to work as well - but now I'm having a second problem. Suppose there is an imported Class in example from another library, how do I get only local Classes?

Comment: It's another question, please post link to it here and I will post an answer there — for the order's sake.

Comment: Limited to a 90 minute timer on asking questions i guess, I'll post later.

Comment: Well, in short, there is no 100% way to determine where did class came from, because of reasons. But for cases where class is defined by class keyword, there is `__module__` field, which is string name of module containing definition. Please note there may be name clash (`foo.Foo` and `bar.foo.Foo` are different classes from different modules, but `__module__` will be `foo` in both cases, AFAIK), as well `__module__` may be None (for dynamic and builtin classes).

Comment: Caveat here is that class reference may be reassigned. `Foo` is defined in module `bar`, but module `buzz` internally imports `bar` and exports `Foo` again. So `buzz.Foo.__module__` will be (surprize!) `'bar'`, not `'buzz'`, as one may expect. Deal with it or redesign your application (because if you need this kind of info, you're almost 100% doing either something crazy or something horribly wrong).

Comment: When I first read this, I thought you were implying that `inspect` (and `isclass`) is only available on python3.x.  Now I see that you're just making links to the python2.x and 3.x documentation.  In my experience, that isn't necessary unless there's a marked difference in the python2/3 behavior which makes it worthwile to point out.